# Document Db storage issue

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am facing the below issue in document Db Storage data movement.

Documentdb issue:portal

```
Copy activity encountered a user error at Sink side: ErrorCode=UserErrorDocumentDBWriteError,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,
Message=DocumentDb operation failed: Message:
 {"Errors":["The MAC signature found in the HTTP request is not the same as
 the computed signature. Server used following string to sign - 
'post\ndocs\nhavtaldabga=\ntue, 06 jun 2017 10:35:07 gmt\n\n'"]}
 ActivityId: 57b1394d-30b0-474b-9301-20df952a6270,
 Request URI: rntbd://dz5prdddc02-docdb-3.documents.azure.com:16780/apps/dcdd1431-42ad-4cc0-add4-8c6892b244c9/services/990992b0-7d60-4abb-898f-9bdc37df30e8/partitions/6b5f150e-2885-4cd8-b37c-1903d0d5ce32/replicas/131411612727727176p/.,
Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.DocumentDb,
''Type=Microsoft.Azure.Documents.UnauthorizedException,
Message=Message: {"Errors":["The MAC signature found in the HTTP request is 
not the same as the computed signature. Server used following string to sign
 - 'post\ndocs\nhavtaldabga=\ntue, 06 jun 2017 10:35:07 gmt\n\n'"]}
ActivityId: 57b1394d-30b0-474b-9301-20df952a6270,
 Request URI: rntbd://dz5prdddc02-docdb-3.documents.azure.com:16780/apps/dcdd1431-42ad-4cc0-add4-8c6892b244c9/services/990992b0-7d60-4abb-898f-9bdc37df30e8/partitions/6b5f150e-2885-4cd8-b37c-1903d0d5ce32/replicas/131411612727727176p/,Source=Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client,'.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The MAC signature found in the HTTP request '...' is not the same as any computed signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30465420/the-mac-signature-found-in-the-http-request-is-not-the-same-as-any-compute)

Comment: Possible duplicate of : The MAC signature found in the HTTP request '...' is not the same as any computed signature

Read info provided here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Authentication-for-the-Azure-Storage-Services?redirectedfrom=MSDN